# Valgrind errors when dynamically resizing array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, tree, valgrind

I am trying to read from a file a list of values that are defined like

```
0001Text here
```

Where the 0001 is the id and the rest is the label.

The file is read in correctly and that part works fine but when I try and add the items to an array that I dynamically resize Valgrind gives these errors:

```
==9005== Invalid read of size 8
==9005==    at 0x108DB0: processFile (in /trees)
==9005==    by 0x108BEE: main (in /trees)
==9005==  Address 0x521d368 is 0 bytes after a block of size 24 alloc'd
==9005==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9005==    by 0x10903E: growArray (in /trees)
==9005==    by 0x108D76: processFile (in /trees)
==9005==    by 0x108BEE: main (in /trees)
==9005== 
==9005== Invalid write of size 8
==9005==    at 0x108DD6: processFile (in /trees)
==9005==    by 0x108BEE: main (in /trees)
==9005==  Address 0x521d368 is 0 bytes after a block of size 24 alloc'd
==9005==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9005==    by 0x10903E: growArray (in /trees)
==9005==    by 0x108D76: processFile (in /trees)
==9005==    by 0x108BEE: main (in /trees)
==9005==
```

I realise that the error is on the line I have marked in the code below but i cannot figure out why these errors are happening. I thought it may be to do with the values not being initialised properly but I'm not sure that is correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct node {
          char  *label;
  unsigned int   n;
} NODE;
typedef NODE TREE;

int growArray(TREE **, int, int);
int processFile(FILE **, char *);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE *fp;   /* the file pointer */

  processFile(&fp, argv[1]);
  return 0;
}

int processFile(char *filename) {
  if ((*fp = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL) {
      printf("Unable to read file: %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
      exit(1);
  }

  /* array to hold all nodes. The index is the nodeID */
  int SIZE = 1;
  TREE *nodes = (TREE *)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(NODE));

  if (nodes == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate initial memory for array.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* checks the line is 4 digits, followed by 63 characters that aren't a */
  /* carriage return or newline                                           */
  int id; char text[64];
  while (fscanf(*fp, " %4d%63[^\r^\n] ", &id, text) == 2){
    SIZE = growArray(&nodes, SIZE, id);

    /* ----------error line---------- */
    nodes[id].label = (char *)realloc(nodes[id].label, (strlen(text)+1));

    strcpy(nodes[id].label, text);

    fprintf(stderr, "%5d: %s\n", id, text);
    return 0;
  }
}

int growArray(TREE **array, int curSize, int id) {
  if (curSize > id) return curSize;

  TREE *temp = (TREE *)realloc(*array, (id * sizeof(NODE)));

  if (temp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate more memory.\n");
    exit(1);
  } else {
    *array = temp;
  }
  return id;
}
```

Where am I going wrong here and what could I do to fix these issues?

Comment: There is not enough code. Please post a [MCVE], emphasis on Minimal.

Comment: A general caveat on `realloc()`... if the new memory block allocation fails, `realloc()` returns `NULL`. If you assign the returned pointer to the old one like you did, and `realloc()` fails, you lost the pointer to the old, still-allocated memory (which you then cannot `free()`).

Comment: Errr.... you can only call `realloc()` on a pointer that was returned from a previous call to `*alloc()`. I don't see you allocating `nodes[id].label` anywhere, you just `realloc()` it...?

Comment: Is memory every allocated for the member: `struct node  **children;` ?

Comment: @ryyker I didn't actually need that line of code, that was left over from a previous program I made

Comment: @DevSolar isn't it allocated when I `realloc()` in grow array?

Comment: @Ollu_, then please clean up the post to make the code you are showing relevant to the problem at hand. Create a [mcve]

Comment: @DevSolar - `calloc` is called in this line: `TREE *nodes = (TREE *)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(NODE));`.  but, no further initializations are made.

Comment: @Ollu_: I did not analyze your code in detail. But the fact that `nodes[].label` is **only** mentioned in context of **re**alloc() makes me think that it *originally* is pointing into a *block* of memory, or worse yet, not pointing anywhere (uninitialized). If you call `realloc()` on anything that has **not** been returned by a previous call to `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`, you are into undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DevSolar you can realloc a null pointer.

Comment: Your problem is in processFile, not in a dynamic resize. processFile overruns the buffer.

Comment: @n.m.: Ah. Right. Well... {retreats into a corner}

Comment: ...And of course processFile is _not included_ in the posted code. ( @Ollu_/ )

Comment: `typedef NODE TREE;`??? That's confusing.  At best.  Because a "tree" seems like it should be able to have many "nodes".

Comment: And if you're going to ignore the `int` return code from `processFile`, just have it return the `FILE *` and not bother with the indirection of `FILE **fp`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array indexes in C are zero-based. You resize your `nodes` array to the size of `id`, and then access `nodes[id]`. It does not exist as it is outside of range [0, id-1]. Thus, valid elements are `nodes[0]` through `nodes[id-1]`.

Comment: my call to `growArray(&nodes, SIZE, id)` to `growArray(&nodes, SIZE, id+1)` and it fixed the original issue. Many thanks.